# data factory data flows - path does not resolve to any file(s)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

trying to set up a data flow to de-duplicate data but there seems to be a simple error that I cannot fix, the data set is set up like so and the preview works correctly - updated file path and imported schema [image]

the data flow is set up like this
[image]

however I get this error when trying Data preview - updated -> got the columns from importing the schema in the dataset

[image]

I have tried editing wildcard paths in source options and so far that has not worked
i tried

```
daily/*csv and *.csv
```

the structure of the blob account looks like so:
[image]

source options from the answer given:
[image]

still the error:  Path does not resolve to any file(s). Please make sure the file/folder exists and is not hidden. At the same time, ensure special character is not included in file/folder name, for example, name start with _

each directory is from an azure export and creates its own monthly folder - this works on data factory but each csv has month to date cost so I was trying to use data flows to only take new data instead of all of the data with duplicates
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the wildcard path below to get the files of the required type.

***Input folder path:***

[image]

***Azure data flow:***

1. Source dataset

[image]

2. Source transformation: In source options provide the wildcard path to get the files of the required extension type. I have also included columns to store filenames to verify the data from all the files.

Wildcard paths : `daily/*.csv`

[image]

3. Import projections and preview data.

[image]

Comment: For some reason it only shows the first file for me